# Found brewing grains in a bunch of paper bags - can I use them?

Tags: brewing, quality, home-brewing

Found a bunch of specialty grains I'd intented for a beer but lost to time. They've been in brown paper bags for well over a year.

Is it worth using them at all for a small batch or has time/air ruined extraction, ruined flavor, etc?

Comment: Can you please ask this on the homebrew stack? https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/